# How to show image in Grouped Header of Devexpress WPF Grid with multiline text?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, wpfdatagrid

I have a grid which displays some data wtih grouping on specific column. I want to display the image that is stored in DB which corresponds to that header Column in WPF. Is it Possible?

Please refer the attachment:

```
<dxg:GridControl Name="grdInfill"  Height="700" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>

            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="GlassType" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="GlassDescription" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="GlassType" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Quantity" AllowEditing="False"  />
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Width" AllowEditing="False" Header="Length"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Height" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Elevation" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Mark" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="GlassTag" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="WallLocation" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="SquareFoot" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Weight" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="UnitCost" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="TotalCost" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="FuelSurcharge" AllowEditing="False"/>

        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView ShowTotalSummary="True" AutoWidth="True" DetailHeaderContent="True" ShowGroupPanel="False" ShowIndicator="False"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>

protected void GetAllInfills()
        {
            List<Infill> infillList = new List<Infill>();
            infillList=BLL.GetAllInfills();
            if (infillList != null)
            {
                grdInfill.ItemsSource = infillList;
                grdInfill.GroupBy(grdInfill.Columns["GlassType"], ColumnSortOrder.Ascending);
                grdInfill.GroupBy(grdInfill.Columns["GlassDescription"], ColumnSortOrder.Ascending);
                grdInfill.AutoExpandAllGroups = true;
            }

        }
```

**I need to display Image on Header section of WPF Grid as shown in Black Image with multiline text**

Help appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I believe the [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) is the best place to get official and guaranteed assistance on the use of DevExpress products. Have you tried it?

Comment: no answer on Devexpress so posted here..! 
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q496898

Comment: It looks like DevExpress has responded to your comment. I'm a little surprised, I would have thought you could use a Grouped Item template to bind the image. Did their answer resolve your issue?

Comment: Sorry but i have removed the image instead of waiting for their response..!